# Dual-Bivariate Kdeplot on the Same Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization, seaborn

I have the following scatterplot:

[image]

The red dots are made shots, the blue ones are missed shots. I have separated the missed shots and made shots into different dataframes, and scattered them onto the same plot. I would now like to create a KDEplot using seaborn, and attempt to use the diverging colormap 'bwr' (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)) to have a plot with the deepest red hues with the highest concentration of red dots, and the deepest blue hues in the highest concentration of blue dots, with a white hue in the zones where the ratio between the two is most balanced. Is this something that is possible to do? If more info is needed, just ask. I am determined to figure this out.

Edit: Here's the scatterplot code, if at all relevant:

```
plt.scatter(made_shots.LOC_X, made_shots.LOC_Y, s=5, c='r')
plt.scatter(missed_shots.LOC_X, missed_shots.LOC_Y, s=5, c='b')
```

Edit 2: Here is the hexbin graph:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to do a kdeplot, something like [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rVRv.png)

Answer (score 2):

A true and tested approach is to make the scatter dots larger and use an alpha to make them semitransparent. That should give a good idea about where the red and blue dots are concentrated.

You could also try out [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html), for example with z=-1 for missed_shots and z=1 for made_shots.

Maybe something like this, although it is very unclear how that would look like with your data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

shots_x = np.concatenate([made_shots.LOC_X, missed.shots_LOC_X])
shots_y = np.concatenate([made_shots.LOC_Y, missed.shots_LOC_Y])
shots_z = np.concatenate([np.repeat(1, len(made_shots)), np.repeat(-1, len(missed_shots))])

plt.tricontourf(shots_x, shots_y, shots_z, cmap='coolwarm')

plt.show()
```

Another possibility could be [`hexbin`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html) which would be called as follows with the above data:

```
plt.hexbin(shots_x, shots_y, C=shots_z, cmap='coolwarm', gridsize=30)
```

Comment: While not exactly what I was looking for, thank you for this. The hexbin approach works much better than what I had working before.

Comment: It would be interesting if you added your final image to the question post. (Without the data it is hard to imagine.)

Comment: Image added. Another minor issue is that now the title is not showing, I'm wondering if it is covered by the graph, but I can solve that later, it isn't a big problem.

Comment: Thanks for the image.  Optionally, you could experiment with the gridsize. To see the title, maybe `plt.tight_layout()` can help. (Or clicking on the configuration icon in the interactive window and moving the top margin.)   Tricontourf might not work for your data because there are too many regions without data.